# Extracting html-as-text between break tags using regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Have a series of elements in a list which are extracted from html -- each with break tags (`<br>...</br>`). I used this code below with one element, and will apply to a loop, but it throws an an error `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing` on the single element.

```
import re

firstElementText = '<td align="center" bgcolor="#e0e0e0" nowrap="" valign="middle"><b>Season</b></td>'

re.search(r'<br>.(.*?)</br>', firstElementText ).group(1)
```

Looking to return `Season` from the search.

Comment: It's time to pull out this answer again! :D http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2588818

Comment: So, it's just a lost cause?

Comment: Generally what you're trying to do is not a lost cause, but parsing HTML with regex is. Just use a regular HTML parser. There are dozens of great ones, several of which are useful from within Python. Try Beautiful Soup.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Two-Bit Alchemist. This is a unique case where newlines are fragmented... darksider's response worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of your HTML:

```
firstElementText = '<td align="center" bgcolor="#e0e0e0" nowrap="" valign="middle"><b>Season</b></td>'
```

Has no `<br>`. Change it to

```
    firstElementText = '<td align="center" bgcolor="#e0e0e0" nowrap="" valign="middle"><br>Season</br></td>'
```

Works for me fine. And, your RegEx should look like that:

```
re.search(r'<br>(.*?)</br>', firstElementText ).group(1)
```

You see the "missing" dot between `>` and `(`?
That will ignore the **first** character that is in the group.
Following works for me fine:

```
>>> import re
>>> firstElementText = '<td align="center" bgcolor="#e0e0e0" nowrap=""       valign="middle"><br>Season</br></td>'
>>> re.search(r'<br>(.*?)</br>', firstElementText ).group(1)
'Season' 
>>>
```

Python 3.4.2.

BTW there is no `<br></br>` out there.
It should be `<br />` because it breaks a line, and doesnt affect it in any other ways...
And as you can read in the comments: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2588818

Comment: Thanks, I see I should have used `<b>&</b>` instead of `<br>&</br>`.